# Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'kf_setImage'

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to execute my code but I am getting the error

> Value of type 'UIImageView' had no member 'kf_setImage'

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Comment: what is the type of `imgProjectIcon` and are you using any third party framework? could you brief in detail

Comment: @PraveenKumar bro imgProjectIcon is type UIImageView and Kingfisher third party i am using

Comment: you are trying to call an unknown function on an object, thats why you get this error

Comment: In the latest documentation of Kingfisher I see next: imageView.kf.setImage(with: url). (not .kf_setImage ). Did you try this?

Comment: @AndrewBogaevskyi Yes bro you are right... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

> ```
> self.imgProjectImage.kf_setImage(with: url)
> ```

should be

```
self.imgProjectImage.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

Answer (score 0):

in [Kingfisher 2.0](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Kingfisher-2.0-Migration-Guide),you should:

```
imageView.kf_setImageWithURL(URL, 
      placeholderImage: nil,
           optionsInfo: optionInfo,
         progressBlock: { receivedSize, totalSize in
         },
     completionHandler: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
     })
```

In [Kingfisher 3.0](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Kingfisher-3.0-Migration-Guide) ,you should:

```
let url = URL(string: "url_of_your_image")
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

please,make sure you use Kingfisher version